# modulus and argument of sum of two exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I tried to find the argument and modulus of :
 $z= \exp(i \theta) + \exp(i2 \theta)$

But i cant reach the answer

After simplification of this number $z$ we get

$\cos(\theta)+\cos(2 \theta) +i(\sin( \theta) +\sin(2 \theta))$

And it's clear that we want to find something like $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ to conclude the argument and modulus.
Even if we use trigonometry identities: sum to product formulas, it's not the right way.

please help!

Comment: None of the answers are in any "simple" form, see (`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(e^(i*a)+e^(2*i*a))`) for the $\vert z \vert$ and (`http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg(cos(a)+i*sin(a)+cos(2*a)+i*sin(2*a)`) for $\text{arg}(z)$. Are you sure there is a $+$ in between, and not a $\cdot$?

Comment: Did you try with duplication formula?

Comment: #Maximilian_Gerhardt
certainly it's + sign in between

Comment: Look at $z\cdot \exp(-3i\theta/2)$.

Comment: @g-cab i can't simplify the expression if i use the duplication
since we are working with C numbers
as cos^2(\theta)-sin^2(\theta) doesn't equaL to 1

Comment: @Student404Mus hup! what do you mean by "working with C numbers $cos^2(\theta)$ + (or minus ?) $sin^2(\theta)$ not equal $1$"?

Comment: @GCab when we square both sides of z=cos(θ)+cos(2θ)+i(sin(θ)+sin(2θ))
z^2=[cos(θ)+cos(2θ)+i(sin(θ)+sin(2θ))]^2=[cos(θ)+cos(2θ)]^2+[i(sin(θ)+sin(2θ)]^2+2[cos(θ)+cos(2θ)]*[i(sin(θ)+sin(2θ))]

then 
from the coming simplification we obtain cos^2θ-sin^2θ "-" arised from i^2 and it's clear cos^2θ-sin^2θ  doesn't equal 1

that's what i were talking about

Answer (score 1):

Plot the two summands onto the gaussian plane, they are two unitary vectors ..
Their sum will lie on the bisecant ...
The module of the sum will be twice the dot product ..